# for loop parameter not working properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, evaluation

Hello: I'm new programming.
My problem is that the evaluation in the `for` sentence is not working properly.

> With: salir='n' it works correctly
>   
>   With: salir=='n' don't works.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tabla="";
    var numusuario=0;
    var min=0;
    var max=9;
    var salir='s';
    numusuario=prompt("Escribe un número entre 0 y 9: ");
    for(var j=1;salir='n';j++) 
    {
        if(numusuario<0 || numusuario>=10)
        {
            salir='s';
            numusuario=prompt("Escribe un número entre 0 y 9: ");
        }
        else
        {
            for(var x=min;x<=max;x++)
            {
                tabla = tabla + x + " x " + numusuario + " = " + (x*numusuario) + "\n";
            }
            alert(tabla);
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you should make deeper research with for loop

Answer (score 2):

`salir='n'` means assignments. it is always return `true`

`salir=='n'` means comparision. it is return `false` because `salir='s'` so `s` is not equal to `n`

Answer (score 0):

Several things happenning here, but main is that you are mixing different forms of flow control:

- You are using `salir` (exit, for non-spanish speakers) as a loop end indicator, but...
- The loop condition is always true (as `salir='n'` evaluates to `'n'`, which is true)
- You are using also a variable, `j`, with no use (you do nothing with it, it doesn't participate in the loop condition neither)
- The only posibility of exiting the loop is the `break` sentence, which exists the loop.

As the expected behaviour is not clear to me, I cannot assume a solution, but if it is to keep running until the user writes a valid number, then write the multiplication table of that number, it could be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tabla="";
    var numusuario=0;
    var min=0;
    var max=9;
    var salir = 'n';

    do {
        numusuario=prompt("Escribe un número entre 0 y 9: ");
        if(numusuario>0 && numusuario<10) {
            for(var x=min;x<=max;x++)
            {
                tabla = tabla + x + " x " + numusuario + " = " + (x*numusuario) + "\n";
            }
            alert(tabla);
            salir = 's';
        }
    } while(salir == 'n')


</script>
```

The `do {} while ()` executes at least once and checks the condition at the end, that seems better suited in this case, we drop the `j` variable and use the `salir` variable as flow control until the user writes the correct number.